# Turning a sentence into the passive voice

Tags: passive-voice

If you turned the sentence:

> He buys a camera

into the passive voice would the sentence then be:

> A camera was bought by him

or something different?

Comment: You've changed both the voice and the tense.  The present-tense passive form is "*is* bought".

Answer (score 0):

> He buys a camera

It just describes one man buys a camera in a plain way.

> A camera was bought by him

It seems like there is no one would buy this camera. This deal makes someone surprised.

Comment: I think we can be very safe in assuming the *Aa* was a typo, not an exclamation. None of what you've written seems to address the topic of the question, which is how to turn an active-voice sentence into a passive-voice sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is almost correct. You have to notice that the verb in the original sentence is in the present tense (buys) and therefore the verb in the passive voice should also be in the present tense:

> A camera **is** bought by him.

Of course, there is no practical purpose for this sentence, but it is grammatically correct - as an exercise for playing with active / passive voices.